# More efficient Javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs, performance

Looking for another eye on making the following Javascript more efficient.

The following JSON is produced from a Resteasy service:

```
var testing = {
   "com:klistret:cmdb:ci:pojo:successful":true,
   "com:klistret:cmdb:ci:pojo:count":1,
   "com:klistret:cmdb:ci:pojo:elements":{
      "com:klistret:cmdb:ci:pojo:id":123,
      "com:klistret:cmdb:ci:pojo:name":"Mars",
      "com:klistret:cmdb:ci:pojo:type":{
        "com:klistret:cmdb:ci:pojo:id":1,
        "com:klistret:cmdb:ci:pojo:name":"Environment"
      },
      "com:klistret:cmdb:ci:pojo:configuration":{
        "@www:w3:org:2001:XMLSchemainstance:type":"Environment",
        "@Watermark":"past",
        "com:klistret:cmdb:ci:commons:Name":"Mars"
      }
    }
 };
```

Extended the Extjs JSONReader to handle key depths higher than 2 in the createAccessor method.  Wondering if there is a way to make the code more efficient?  The function below will be called like `function(testing, "com:klistret:cmdb:ci:pojo:configuration.@Watermark")` where the `com:klistret:cmdb:ci:pojo:elements` property is the root.

```
createAccessor : function(){
    var re = /[\[\.]/;

    return function(expr) {
        if(Ext.isEmpty(expr)){
            return Ext.emptyFn;
        }

        if(Ext.isFunction(expr)){
            return expr;
        }

        # THIS FUNCTION I WANT TO BE EFFICIENT
        return function(obj){
         while (String(expr).search(re) !== -1) {
 var i = String(expr).search(re);
 var key = expr.substring(0, i);

 if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  obj = obj[key];
 }

 expr = expr.substring(i+1, expr.length);
}

            return obj[expr];
        };
    };
}()
```

Comment: Why does your code scan convert expr to a string twice per loop and then fail to convert it to a string before calling substring?  Can't the string coercion be moved outside the loop entirely?  Ideally, outside the inner function too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use. I only allow dot annotation, mind:

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.JsonReader, {
  createAccessor: function() {
    return function(expr) {
      if (Ext.isEmpty(expr)) {
        return Ext.emptyFn;
      } else if (Ext.isFunction(expr)) {
        return expr;
      } else {
        return function(obj) {
          var parts = (expr || '').split('.'),
              result = obj,
              part,
              match;
          while (parts.length > 0 && result) {
            part = parts.shift();
            match = part.match(/^(.+?)(\[(\d+)\])?$/);
            result = result[match[1]];
            if (result && match[3]) {
              result = result[match[3]];
            }
          }
          return result;
        }
      }
    };
  }()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A basic optimization would be to avoid scanning the string twice with `search`, which is pretty slow.

The best you could do is replace all the string scanning and substring extraction with a single call to `expr.split('.')`, which would support accessors of the form `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd` and turn them into an array like `['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd']`. The other two characters you seem to support (`[` and `]`) wouldn't work.

Alternately, you could do an initial match for `/[^\].[]+/g` over your entire string and keep the matches to obtain a similar array, but this would possibly be slower than the previous solution.